# Does glUseProgram alter VAO and/or VBO state?

Tags: opengl

Is the currently-installed shader program part of the VAO state and/or part of the VBO state?  Or is it separate state that is not affected when VAO and VBO are switched?

According to [these docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUseProgram.xhtml) the `glUseProgram` function

> Installs a program object as part of current rendering state.

In other words, how is "rendering state" is defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, active shader is not a part of VAO nor VBO state.

By *"rendering state"* they seem to mean the *global* state.